# Can I access LDAP (AD) via JNDI in a Blackberry App?

Tags: java, blackberry, ldap, jndi

I want to authenticate a user against our Active Directory database on a BlackBerry mobile app.
I've written J2EE apps that authenticate against AD using JNDI (javax.naming).
I've also written BlackBerry apps that do local data access and remote JSON interaction.

In this app, I need to limit access to the back-end servlet based on their AD access.
I do not have access to change the servlet, so I can't pass authentication credentials to it.

Thanks in advance for your input.